# Tezbox Web Wallet to Tezbox Windows Wallet App

Tags: tezbox

I have a wallet using the web version of the Tezbox wallet, where I see my coins.

I downloaded the Windows app of Tezbox and tried restoring my wallet using my seed phrase and it gives me a new wallet with a different address and a 0 balance.

Any idea how to migrate my web wallet to the app?

Comment: Tezos Stack Exchange is for specific technical questions. Product/wallet support inquiries should be directed at Telegram, Riot, Reddit.